# Django class Meta, зачем?

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Обясните, зачем нужен класс `Meta`?

Допустим, в таком коде:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'description',)
```

И иногда встречается в моделях.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django во многом работает через метаклассы.

Если коротко, то метаклассы - это классы, которые конструируют другие классы. Объявляются они через атрибут класса __metaclss__ (в джанге через слой совместимости с python 3 через six.with_metaclass).

Поэтому когда Django конструирует ваш класс `PostForm`, например, она делает это с помощью своего метакласса. Чтобы при конструировании ей знать какие-то параметры вашего класса, ну, например модель или поля в вашем случае, она ищет в вашем классе класс с названием Meta (да, `class ClassName:` без наследования - это старый вариант объявления классов, доставшийся в наследство от старых версий python, он отличается от `object`).

Вообще вся эта магия с метаклассами очень важна в джанге и поэтому лучше саму логику становления класса не переопределять.

Если взять за пример `ModelForm`, то можно посмотреть на [код джанги](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5ec64f96b2d83ec3c0ef574f52e4767a440017b8/django/forms/models.py#L459):

```
class ModelForm(six.with_metaclass(ModelFormMetaclass, BaseModelForm)):
    pass
```

`ModelFormMetaclass` - это тот самый метакласс, который конструирует класс `ModelForm`. Например, код

```
opts = new_class._meta = ModelFormOptions(getattr(new_class, 'Meta', None))
```

получает тот самый метакласс, если посмотреть [дальше по коду](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5ec64f96b2d83ec3c0ef574f52e4767a440017b8/django/forms/models.py#L193) - что-то делает с полями `['fields', 'exclude', 'localized_fields']`

Попробуйте разобраться что и как там действует - код таких фреймворков очень интересен для изучения - как для практики, так и для получения новых знаний

Comment: Спасибо за очень крутой ответ!