# Не могу понять зачем использовать Meta класс в Python

Tags: python, django

Пример кода с Django

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):

        model = CustomUser 

        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.forms
```

Вообще в проекте сам не пользуюсь с Meta классов а в Django часто вижу

```
  class User():
       class Meta:
```

Зачем пользоваться !

Comment: Вот ответ [Django class Meta, зачем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539475/django-class-meta-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc?rq=1) Немного гугла вам бы помогло

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том что я не смог понять суть ! Вот и обращался сюда .

Comment: Теперь стало понятнее?:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Django class Meta, зачем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539475/django-class-meta-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: В документации это описано. Что именно в ней осталось вам непонятно?